# How can I use `std::array` for a template parameter of the form `template<typename> class`?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-templates

Please consider the following `tree` class

```
template<typename T, template<typename> class Tuple>
class tree
{
private:
    T m_value;
    Tuple<tree> m_children;
};

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
using static_tree = tree<T, std::array<T, N>>;
```

which is not well-defined. `std::array<T, N>` is not a suitable template parameter for `Tuple`. I assume the intend of `static_tree` is clear. We could do something like

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct helper
{
    template<typename T>
    using type = std::array<T, N>;
};

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
using static_tree = tree<T, helper<N>::template type>;
```

Is there any other option without the `helper` class?

Comment: If you own `tree`, why not make `Tuple`  a type parameter rather than a template parameter?

Comment: @AlanStokes How would I define `static_tree` in that case? That would be an endless recursion, wouldn't it?

Comment: The fact is, `std::array` needs an integer parameter. There's no way around specifying it *somewhere*. As to where this is, there are many alternatives, and yours is not far from obvious.

Comment: @davidhigh I hoped there would be some kind of `bind` for template parameters.

Comment: @0xbadf00d : There are quite a few implementations of that, but they cannot generalize to non-type template parameters as those don't mix with parameter packs.

Comment: Your helper is already a kind of `bind`, but an explicit one. A more general one is not possible as mentioned by @idljarn: the reason for this is that you cannot generally state the template parameters of the resulting class template ... you can't use a parameter pack for that, as at each position you could also have non-type template parameter.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than having the helper function be an exception for `std::array`, I'd propose that be the rule. Instead of taking a template template parameter, take a *metafunction class* parameter. Template metaprogramming is a lot easier when everything everywhere is a type (avoiding template templates and non-type arguments):

```
template<typename T, typename TupleMfn>
class tree
{
private:
    using Tuple = TupleMfn::template apply<tree>;

    T m_value;
    Tuple m_children;
};
```

with:

```
template <size_t N>
struct array_builder {
    template <class T>
    using apply = std::array<T, N>;
};

template <typename T, size_t N>
using static_tree = tree<T, array_builder<N>>;
```

This will make it easier to use with other kinds of containers as well, since we can make a wrapper for template templates that gives us back a metafunction:

```
template <template <typename...> class X>
struct as_metafunction {
    template <class... Args>
    using apply = X<Args...>;
}; 

template <typename T>
using vector_tree = tree<T, as_metafunction<std::vector>>;
```

---

If you're feeling especially feisty, you can provide a metaprogramming-friendly version of `std::array`:

```
template <class T, class N>
struct meta_array : std::array<T, N::value> // obviously I am terrible at naming things
{ };

template <size_t N>
using size_t_ = std::integral_constant<size_t, N>;
```

And then provide placeholder args for `tree` to apply:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
using static_tree = tree<T, meta_array<_, size_t_<N>>>;

template <class T>
using vector_tree = tree<T, std::vector<_>>;
```

Comment: Your `tree` is *not* a tree, since `m_children` is a tuple of `T`'s.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question contains a fundamental problem which is different from what you were explicitly asking (it threw me off a bit in the previous iteration of this answer). Combining the different parts of your question, you're essentially trying to instantiate some tree class that has a member that is an `std::array` of the same class as well. This is obviously impossible. You probably want that the tree should hold some `Tuple` of *pointers* (smart or otherwise).

One way to do so would be to use your helper class, but modifying the class to

```
template<typename T, template<typename> class Tuple>
class tree
{
    // Indirection (I'm omitting the question of whether these should be
    //     smart pointers.
    Tuple<tree<T, Tuple> *> m_children;
};
```

A different way would make `Tuple` a regular template parameter, as follows:

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, class Tuple>
class tree                                                                                                                                  
{
private:
    static_assert(
        std::is_same<void *, typename Tuple::value_type>::value, 
        "Tuple must be a container of void *");

private:
    T m_value;
    Tuple m_children;
};

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
using static_tree = tree<T, std::array<void *, N>>;

int main()
{
    static_tree<int, 8> t;
}
```

On the one hand, the helper class has been eliminated. OTOH, `Tuple` is a container of `void *`: the instantiators are aware of this, and the class internally needs to perform casts. It's a tradeoff. I would stick to your original version (with the modifications suggested, of course).

Comment: You know that with your definition `static_tree` is *not* a tree, right? The children of a tree need to be trees too.

Comment: @0xbadf00d You're right, but upon reflection, I think that was caused by some problem in your question. See update.

Answer (score 0):

A class X cannot contain multiple copies of actual instances of class X, except logically.

An if we have

```
struct X {
  std::array<X, 2> data;
};
```

the only possible size for `X` is infinity, as `sizeof(X)` = `2*sizeof(X)`, and all types in C++ have `sizeof(X)>=1`.

C++ does not support infinitely large types.

Your second problem is that type instances are not templates.

```
template<typename T, template<typename> class Tuple>
class tree
```

this takes a type `T` and a `template` `Tuple`.  The second argument *is not a type*.

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
using static_tree = tree<T, std::array<T, N>>;
```

here, your second argument *is a type*, not a template.

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct array_of_size {
  template<class T>
  using result=std::array<T,N>;
};
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
using static_tree = tree<T, array_of_size<N>::template result>;
```

would, other than the above "infinite size problem", solve your problem.  Here we are passing the template `array_of_size<N>::result` to `tree`.

To solve the infinite size problem, you *must* store pointers (or something equivalent) in the array.  So we get:

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct array_of_ups_of_size {
  template<class T>
  using result=std::array<std::unique_ptr<T>,N>;
};
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
using static_tree = tree<T, array_of_ups_of_size<N>::template result>;
```

and now your static_tree has `N` children, each of which is a `unique_ptr` to a similar `static_tree`.

This still doesn't work, because of destructor issues.

```
template<typename T, template<typename> class Tuple>
class tree
{
private:
  T m_value;
  Tuple<tree> m_children;
public:
  ~tree();
};

template<typename T, template<typename> class Tuple>
tree<T,Tuple>::~tree() = default;
```

I think the above fixes it, strange as it may seem.

Basically, when you make the array of children, the tree type is incomplete.  At destruction, delete is called.  At that point, tree must be complete.  By deferring the dtor, we hopefully deal with the problem.

I am uncertain if this technique is required for templates, but it is for non-template classes.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could implement a template parameter bind as you suggested (slightly more general than your `helper`):

```
template<std::size_t N, template<typename,std::size_t> class T>
struct bind2nd
{
    template<typename F>
    using type = T<F,N>;
};

template<std::size_t N, typename T>
using static_tree = tree<T, bind2nd<N,std::array>::template type>;
```